# pro's and cons of MEF vs Portable Areas via MvcContrib for collaborative programming

Tags: asp.net-mvc, mef, mvccontrib

I've been looking into MEF and Portable areas and the pro's and cons of using these in a collaborative programming environment.

I've found the following article

http://www.thegecko.org/index.php/2010/06/pluggable-mvc-2-0-using-mef-and-strongly-typed-views/

which states

> MEF was chosen over other solutions
>   such as Portable Areas as it allows
>   all plugins to be composed together as
>   a single site at runtime without the
>   assemblies needing to reference each
>   other.

I haven't found any real in depth comparisons between the two technologies, although I did find the following question which didn't have any answers.

http://mef.codeplex.com/Thread/View.aspx?ThreadId=210370

Have spent a while searching, does anyone have any experience with these two technologies and/or insight into situations where one would be preferable over the other?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've never used Portable Areas, but I do think it is worth mentioning that one big benefit of MEF over other solutions in my mind is simply that [MEF is now included in Framework 4.0](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/archive/blogs/gblock/mef-has-shipped).  If it is true that Portable Areas requires assemblies to reference each other, that would seem to be a big negative compared to MEF (that is if a pluggable architecture is important to you).